# How can I move my shopify product price to another line?

Tags: shopify

I am currently trying to adjust the location of my price in shopify. On desktop view, it is to the right of the title which fits perfectly. For mobile, I want to move the price to below the title since phones don't have as much space to work with. I will insert the code below and what it looks like on mobile and desktop.

Code:

[image: Code]

Desktop:

[image: Desktop]

Mobile:

[image: Mobile]

Comment: add `align-items:flex-start` also for mobile devices, it aligns the price below the title.

Comment: That didn't move it at all. Still to the right of the title.

Comment: Without check over the website, nobody know what is the actual issue, so post the link to page

Comment: website is: www.primallifting.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the CSS at the end of the `CSS` file

```
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
    .template-collection .product-details-div,
    .product-recommendations .product-details-div{ 
      flex-direction:column; 
     }


    .template-collection .product-details-div-price, 
    .product-recommendationsproduct-details-div-price {
      margin-top: 3px;
    }
}
```

and it looks like this if no conflict with other CSS.
[image]

Comment: That fixed my issue! Thank you very much.

Comment: Always happy to help

Comment: Now, my related products are doing the same thing my collection products did. Any fix on this?

Comment: The related products can be found on the product page underneath the description.

Comment: Update the answer, now it will works with the product recommendation section also.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!